# NSTableView textfield cell should not go into edit on click

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nstableview, nstextfield

I have two `NSTableView`s in my app and both are set up the same, same parameters, etc., they have several columns with `NSTextField` cells and the first column is editable.

The first table behaves like I want it: if the user clicks, the row is selected. If the user clicks the row a second time the textfield goes into edit mode, letting the user change the text in it.

The second table should act the same but it doesn't: if I click a row in it, most of the time it goes straight into edit mode with the textfield. Very, very rarely this does not happen.

Does anyone know what causes this? I checked all parameters (in IB) and code and they are the same on both tables. If I set 'Refuses first responder' on the textfield in the naughty table, it doesn't let me edit the textfield at all so that option doesn't help.

Comment: Check if both tables have same `Highlight` property value.

Comment: They have both a Highlight value set to Regular. so that doesn't seem to be related to the issue.

Comment: One important detail: It only happens when clicked on the text, not when clicked into the empty area of a row. Still, both tables and sub views are identical so I wonder why it happens on one table and not the other.

Comment: Are the two NSTextFields configured exactly the same way? Does your code modify one or another?

Comment: Yes, they are the same. I even deleted the one in question and copied over the non-troubling one. I found out that it might be related to `NSTableView.doubleAction`. I use a base class for the view controllers of both tables and set `_tableView.doubleAction = "onDoubleClick:"`. If I comment it out the issue with 2nd table doesn't happen. But the first table acts correct with or without the double action. What could it be?

Comment: solved it! see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED IT! The reason why it works on the first table view but caused the edit issue on the second table was because the first table allows dragging while the second did not! It seems somehow this interferes with `doubleAction` (I even read somewhere that an editable table cannot have `doubleAction` but it seems to work without problems). I could fix it by implementing `tableView(_:writeRowsWithIndexes:toPasteboard:)` in the second tableview's view controller and simply return `false` (since the 2. table should not have drag'n'drop ability) ...

```
func tableView(aTableView:NSTableView, writeRowsWithIndexes rowIndexes:NSIndexSet, toPasteboard pboard:NSPasteboard) -> Bool
{
    return false;
}
```